# Download all the processed files generated on the fly as zip file on client side (without saving processed files on Server/Database) in Django Python

Tags: python, django, client, web-development-server, python-zipfile

I want to download all the processed files generated in a program as a zip file on client system on the fly without storing them on the server/database side.

I am working on Django framework.

The idea is to take multiple files as input from the user, perform some processing on excel files and then download those files as a single zipfile (on the fly) at the client end without storing them on server

**To achieve this, what I did is:**

```
**In my views.py file:**

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
import io

# creating a zip file object outside any function so that its accessible to all the functions in the views.py file (**Not sure if this is the right way of doing it**)
zipObj = ZipFile('sample.zip', 'w')

# This function identifies if the file is excel
def myfiletype(fname):
    filename = fname
    # Get file extension
    file_ext = filename.split(".")[-1]

    # check if extension matches type of file we expect:
    if file_ext.lower() in ("xls", "xlsx"):
        return "excel"

    return "unrecognized"

@csrf_exempt
def files_processing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file')

        # process each file:
        for file in files:
            if myfiletype(str(file)) == 'excel':
                excel_processor(file)
            
            else:
                pass

    return render(request, "files_processing.html")

def excel_processor(file):
    myfile = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    # For now, assume in this function, I just create a new file and copying the text to new file
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file.name.split(".")[0] + "_processed.xlsx", engine = "xlsxwriter")
    
    for sheet_name in myfile.sheet_names:
        df = pd.read_excel(my_file, sheet_name)
        # for now we assume we are simply copying content of one excel file to another and append the name with _processed in the filename
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    writer.close()

   # Here I am writing this excel file to zipObj directly, which **I am not sure is the right way of doing the things**
   zipObj.write(file.name.split(".")[0] + "_processed.xlsx")


def download_zip(request):
    my_zip_file = zipObj
    
    #create an inmemory file like object for the zip data:
    in_memory_zip = io.BytesIO()
    filenames = my_zip_file.namelist()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(in_memory_zip, mode="w") as zf:
        # Add each file to the zip archive
        for filename in filenames:
            file_data = my_zip_file.read(filename)
            zf.writestr(filename, file_data)
   
    # create a response containing the zip data:
    response = HttpResponse(in_memory_zip.getvalue(), content_type="application/zip")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="processed_files.zip"'

    return response

**# In my "files_processing.html" file, I have:**

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type = "file" name="file" multiple>
      <input type = "submit" value="Process files">
      </form>
      <br>
      <a href = "{% url 'download-zip' %}">Download Processed Files </a>
</body>
</html>


# In my "urls.py", I have:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from sample_project import views # Note: sample_project is the name of my project in VS Code

urlpatterns = [
    path("files/", views.files_processing, name="files_processing"),
    path("download-zip/", views.download_zip, name="download-zip")
]
```

After performing the above steps, what's actually happening is:

- When I first run this program, it is taking the file input from user, performs excel processing and downloading the zip file perfectly as well :)
- **But THE ISSUE IS -- after the first run, when I am running for processing other files, the files that were processed earlier (in the previous runs) are still coming as part of that processed_files.zip file!!**

**My expectation is -->** fresh batch of files should have only those excels which were uploaded in that particular instance of processing.

I am new to Python Django, any lead on this as to why it may be happening or how we can resolve it, is highly appreciated.

Please let me know if anything is unclear/ambiguous in the above code.